# Back facing camera not working - fatal exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-camera, fatal-error

It worked perfectly with front camera but is not working with back camera.

In the IF statement, condition must be (cameraId < 1) right? Am I right about that?
couldn't figure out what's causing the error.

Also, when the condition is changed to camId > 0, it gives the toast message. So clearly the returned value must be 0 as expected. Why is this causing the error then?

Here's my code and Logcat:

```
   package com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MagnifyActivity extends Activity { // same as MirrorActivity with
                                                // different camPreview
    // Fields -----------------------------------------------------------------
    private Camera camera = null;
    private MirrorViewmg camPreview = null;
    private FrameLayout previewLayout = null;
    private int cameraId = -1 ;

    // Methods ----------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_magnify);
        // Find out if we even have a camera
        if (!getPackageManager()
                .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No camera feature on this device",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            // Get the ID of the back facing camera
            cameraId = findFirstBackFacingCamera();
            //Log.d(DEBUG_TAG,"value of cameraid=", cameraId);
            // If we have a valid camera
            if (cameraId < 1) {

                // Get the preview frame and strip it of all of it's views
                previewLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camPreviewmg);
                previewLayout.removeAllViews();

                // Start the camera
                startCameraInLayout(previewLayout, cameraId);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No back facing camera found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if (camera != null) {
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (camera == null && previewLayout != null) {
            previewLayout.removeAllViews();
            startCameraInLayout(previewLayout, cameraId);
        }
    }

    private int findFirstBackFacingCamera() {
        int foundId = -1;
        int numCams = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int camId = 0; camId < numCams; camId++) {

            // Get the camera information
            CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camId, info);

            // Check to see if this is a back facing camera
            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                foundId = camId;
                break;
            }
        }
        return foundId;
    }

    private void startCameraInLayout(FrameLayout layout, int cameraId) {
        camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
        if (camera != null) {

            // Create a new MirrorView object and
            // add the view to the FrameLayout
            camPreview = new MirrorViewmg(this, camera);
            layout.addView(camPreview);

        }
    }

    /*
     * @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { // Inflate the
     * menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     * getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.magnify, menu); return true; }
     */

}
```

Log:

```
 04-23 21:56:36.885: D/AndroidRuntime(31421): Shutting down VM
04-23 21:56:36.885: W/dalvikvm(31421): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416b0d40)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421): Process: com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit, PID: 31421
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit/com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.MagnifyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.MirrorViewmg.<init>(MirrorViewmg.java:22)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.MagnifyActivity.startCameraInLayout(MagnifyActivity.java:94)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit.MagnifyActivity.onCreate(MagnifyActivity.java:43)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
04-23 21:56:36.889: E/AndroidRuntime(31421):    ... 11 more
04-23 21:56:38.418: I/Process(31421): Sending signal. PID: 31421 SIG: 9
```

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.iamtheonewhoknocks.toolkit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        flashlightButton();
        calculatorButton();

        mirrorButton();

        converterButton();
        mgglassButton();
        timerButton();

    }

    private void flashlightButton() {
        ImageButton flButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flashButton);
        flButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        FlashlightActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }

    private void calculatorButton() {
        ImageButton flButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.calcButton);
        flButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        CalculatorActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }

    private void mirrorButton() {
        ImageButton mrButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mirrorButton);
        mrButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        MirrorActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }

    private void converterButton() {
        ImageButton flButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.converterButton);
        flButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        ConverterActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }

    private void mgglassButton() {
        ImageButton mrButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.mglassButton);
        mrButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        MagnifyActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }

    private void timerButton() {
        ImageButton mrButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.timerButton);
        mrButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, TimerActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { // Inflate the
     * menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     * getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); return true; }
     */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be `cameraid >= 0`.

Comment: nope. doesn't work. 
I dont get it..camId returns a value ), right.. since CAMERA_FACING_BACK has a value 0?
why is this not working?

Comment: Also, when the condition is changed to camId > 0, it gives the toast message. So clearly the returned value must be 0 as expected. Why is this causing the error then?

Comment: This is a common misunderstanding with Camera API. cameraId counts the cameras (0, 1, ..., numberOfCameras-1), but the value of CAMERA_FACING_BACK has no relation to this, and just *happens* to be 0. Anyways, the result of `findFirstBackFacingCamera()` is invalid if it is -1, meaning that no facing back camera was found. I don't think this is what causes the `NullPointerException`, though. What is on line 22 of your `MirrorViewmg.java` file?